# A problem about a general assertion in equivalent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $n=2$ , it is easy to conclude that $A\in M_{n}$ is not diagonally equivalent to a matrix with distinct eigenvalues if and only if $A$ is singular and every principal minor of $A$ of size $n-1$ is zero.But how can prove it when $n>2$ ? My book said it is not so difficult.I can not solve this problem. Should I use mathematical induction to solve it?

Comment: Yes, try that (induction).

Comment: @mjw Thanks for your comment! But I have difficulties in using induction beacuse I can not find the conncetion.